# Android: get DatePickerDialog in a fragment

Tags: android, datepicker, fragment

Previously i was using **showDialog()** which now is deprecated.

I am already in a **Fragment** which contains an EditText. How can i call this **DatePickerDialog** and set the EditText's Text to the selected date?

Using **DialogFragment** seems a bit complicated.

Thank You

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its easy:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();
    }
};

DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
        R.style.MyThemee, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
d.show();
```

UpdateDisplay method:

```
private void updateDisplay() {

    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");

    editDate.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    transDateString=sdf.format(c.getTime());
}// updateDisplay
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at android API guides :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog