# How to get the values from datepicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a DatePicker in my app.I need to get the values of the date that are selected???

for example:

```
 dateDisplay=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
```

As we do in normal edittext like:

```
final EditText Name = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.nametext); 
and we can cast the data of it by using `Name.getText().toString()`
```

So similarly how can we get the values of date picker to a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting and getting values from date picker and time picker in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592499/casting-and-getting-values-from-date-picker-and-time-picker-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

[Android: get DatePickerDialog in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082861/android-get-datepickerdialog-in-a-fragment/13082956#13082956)

---

Its easy:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();
    }
};

DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
        R.style.MyThemee, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
d.show();
```

UpdateDisplay method:

```
private void updateDisplay() {

    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");

    editDate.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    transDateString=sdf.format(c.getTime());
}// updateDisplay
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work like charm.

```
 final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       pYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
       pMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
       pDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//----------To Open datePicker----------------
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
     {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
            {
                pYear = year;
                pMonth = monthOfYear;
                pDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
     };

//----------To display date in EditText----------------
private void updateDisplay()
     {
           final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
           currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

           displayBirthdayDate.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                        // Month is 0 based so add 1
                        .append(pMonth + 1).append("/")
                        .append(pDay).append("/")
                        .append(pYear));
     }
```